# Webhook not working

Tags: jira, webhooks, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

I have already done the following:
1) Created a project in JIRA with name "Project1" and added a work flow "WF1" to it.
2) Created a webhook "WB1"and added that webhook as a post function to the work flow "WF1".

Now I am trying to call a Java Rest API from webhook "WB1".
The url for my Rest API is "http://PC93112.uk.rebushr.com:8080/JIRAIntegration/rest/JiraService/records"
Any help is greatly appreciated
Now the QUESTION is : How can I pass the issue key (Issue which has been edited in JIRA) to my Rest API. When I tried the below URL I am getting the text “${issue.key}” instead of the issue key. 
http://PC93112.uk.rebushr.com:8080/JIRAIntegration/rest/JiraService/records?issue=${issue.key}

Comment: Which transition did you add the postfunction to? For which events does your webhook get triggered? What version of jira do you use?

Answer (score 1):

The [JIRA webhook documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/webhooks) mentions this limitation, which could be the reason:

> If you are using JIRA 5.2.2 or earlier, there is a known issues when using JQL with webhooks:
>   The ${issue.key} variable replacement does not work in a webhook, when the webhook is used in a workflow post function. Note, the ${issue.key} variable replacement does work when an issue event triggers the webhook.

If that's not it, you could also configure your webhook to include a body in its requests which will mention info about the affected issue like this:

```
"issue": { 
    "expand":"renderedFields,names,schema,transitions,operations,editmeta,changelog",
    "id":"99291",
    "self":"https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/2/issue/99291",
    "key":"JRA-20002",
    "fields":{
        "summary":"I feel the need for speed",
        "created":"2009-12-16T23:46:10.612-0600",
        "description":"Make the issue nav load 10x faster",
        "labels":["UI", "dialogue", "move"],
        "priority": "Minor"
    }
}
```